# Add Custom XML Part using Apache POI

Tags: java, xml, excel, apache-poi

What is the proper way to add custom XML Part to XLSX file using Apache POI?

I have tried creating package part and add relation to workbook using the code below, but my newly added part is added as blank file because the workbook clears package parts in `POIXMLDocument#prepareForCommit()`.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class AddCustomXmlPart {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String outputFileName = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Documents/test-updated.xlsx";

        try {
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            workbook.createSheet("Test");
            addCustomXmlPart(workbook);

            workbook.write(new FileOutputStream(outputFileName));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void addCustomXmlPart(XSSFWorkbook workbook) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        final OPCPackage opcPackage = workbook.getPackage();
        final PackagePartName partName = PackagingURIHelper.createPartName("/customXml/item1.xml");
        final PackagePart part = opcPackage.createPart(partName, ContentTypes.PLAIN_OLD_XML);
        final OutputStream outputStream = part.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write("<test>A</test>".getBytes());
        outputStream.close();

        final PackageRelationship packageRelationship = part.addRelationship(
                partName, TargetMode.INTERNAL, PackageRelationshipTypes.CUSTOM_XML);

        final POIXMLDocumentPart documentPart = new POIXMLDocumentPart(workbook, part, packageRelationship);
        workbook.addRelation(packageRelationship.getId(), documentPart);
    }
}
```

Comment: One quick fix would be to do it in two steps, firstly write your workbook, then open the new OPCPackage + add the new part to it

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, although it did not work. I wrote the file to disk after creation and added custom xml part after loading it to XSSFWorkbook and I got exactly the same result - blank /customXml/item1.xml file.

Comment: No, write it with XSSFWorkbook, stop using any XSSF bits, read it back with only OPC classes, add the extra part, write it back out with OPCPackage

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by Gagravarr:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class AddCustomXmlUsingOpc {
    public static final String PARENT_PATH = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Documents/";
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String outputFileName1 = PARENT_PATH + "01.xlsx";
        String outputFileName2 = PARENT_PATH + "02.xlsx";

        try {
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            workbook.createSheet("Test");
            workbook.write(new FileOutputStream(outputFileName1));

            final OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(new File(outputFileName1));
            addCustomXmlPart(opcPackage);
            opcPackage.save(new File(outputFileName2));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void addCustomXmlPart(OPCPackage opcPackage) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        final PackagePartName partName = PackagingURIHelper.createPartName("/customXml/item1.xml");
        final PackagePart part = opcPackage.createPart(partName, ContentTypes.PLAIN_OLD_XML);
        final OutputStream outputStream = part.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write("<test>A</test>".getBytes());
        outputStream.close();

        part.addRelationship(partName, TargetMode.INTERNAL, PackageRelationshipTypes.CUSTOM_XML);

        final PackagePartName workbookName = PackagingURIHelper.createPartName("/xl/workbook.xml");
        final PackagePart workbookPart = opcPackage.getPart(workbookName);
        workbookPart.addRelationship(partName, TargetMode.INTERNAL, PackageRelationshipTypes.CUSTOM_XML);
    }

}
```