# Update sheet data in XLSX and save using PackagePart

Tags: java, excel, xlsx

I have a large XLSX file (about 200k-300k rows in it). I need to open it in Java, change some values on several sheets and then close it.

I tried to use Apache POI but it takes so long create a workbook. So I found SXSSF decision but it takes XSSFWorkbook as template which I can't create due to long creating of a workbook. Then I decided to open XLSX-file as OPCPackage, get sheets, change them and save file. I used sample code from here ([Add Custom XML Part using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561366/add-custom-xml-part-using-apache-poi)) but I don't get how to change data in existing sheet.

Here's my code:

```
    String filename = "temp.xlsx";
    OPCPackage pkg = null;
    int sheetID = 3;
    try 
    {
        pkg = OPCPackage.open(filename);
        PackagePart part = pkg.getPart(PackagingURIHelper.createPartName("/xl/worksheets/sheet" + sheetID + ".xml"));
        InputStream is = part.getInputStream();
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("c");
        for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node nNode = nList.item(i);

                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                        String cellType = eElement.getAttribute("t");
                        if(cellType.equals("s"))
                        {
                            eElement.getElementsByTagName("v").item(0).setTextContent("62");
                        }
                }
        }
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(bos);
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        is.close();
        //InputStream newIs = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
        //bos.toByteArray()
        //part.load(newIs);
        byte[] arr = bos.toByteArray();
        System.out.println(arr.length);
        OutputStream os = part.getOutputStream();
        os.write(arr);
        os.close();
    }
    catch(Throwable ex) 
    {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        ex.printStackTrace(pw);
        System.out.println(sw.toString());  
    }
    finally {
        try
        {
            pkg.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
            e.printStackTrace(pw);
            System.out.println(sw.toString()); 
        }
    }
```

In the end I open my file as zip archive and sheet3.xml is empty. Should I save changes somehow?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You might want to look at VBA or VBScript if they are options to you

Comment: @GaryEvans, no I need to make changes in Java

Comment: I changed this code slightly so it works now. But I can't post answer due to ban reason :(