# How can I pass data via a Word document from a Java-Server to a JS Add-In?

Tags: javascript, java, ms-word, apache-poi, office-addins

What I want to do is storing data on the server-side inside a word document using Java and Apache POI and read that data from inside a Word Add-In written in JavaScript. (On a sidenote: Personally I'm only working on the JS part of this, the Java part is done by someone else.)

Now, I need to support Word 2016 on Windows which means I cannot use WordApi requirement sets 1.3 and 1.2. This means that (as far as I can tell) I cannot use Custom Properties, which would be perfect. An alternative I've found are Custom XML Parts. But this is where I'm stuck right now.

We found this solution for the Java part: [Add Custom XML Part using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561366/add-custom-xml-part-using-apache-poi)

But I don't know how I can read that data using the JavaScript APIs. There are two functions to read "Custom XML Parts": (accessible through the object `Office.context.document.customXmlParts`) `getByIdAsync()` and `getByNamespaceAsync()` (both are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.customxmlparts?view=excel-js-preview)). Even after unzipping the generated word document I can see the added custom XML, so writing works fine. But there is no ID (which should be a GUID according to the docs) nor a namespace. So, I don't know how I can access this data.

Are both sides talking about the same type of "Custom XML Parts"? And how can I achieve my goal? I'm open to all kind of solutions: Using a different JS API, different Java API, or both.

Comment: why not add a part via the word api and then unzip/adapt it with POI?

Comment: Only the server knows the data that I need to read in the add-in. This data depends on "where" I download the document from a Java application. I've unzipped the document only for debugging purposes. I wanted to know if the data was present and if I can find information about how I could access it. Or what do you mean by "via the word api"? The information flow should be Java/POI -> JavaScript/WordApi, not vice versa.

Comment: the thought is: "there is no ID" -> I need to create an ID on the server side, how does it look like? client side (i.e. your front end devel pc): open example word document -> call addAsync with an ID -> unzip the docx and check the surrounding/parent xml of the custom part, then on server side: change the custom xml to look like your client xml + fixed id, then on client side: call getByIdAsync with the predefined id

Comment: Ah, thanks. That sounds like an idea. I'll try that.

Comment: Both results are very different. The XML created from the JS API are inside a `customXml` folder with two files per part. One `item<num>.xml` with the content and `itemProps<num>.xml` with meta data and the GUID (`<num>` is an auto-increment value). POI on the other hand creates an entirely new folder structure next to the `customXml` folder where parts of the XML are turned into folders.

Comment: If you have problems generating those entries, you can send me that .docx to my apache email and I'll try to provide you with the sample code ...

Answer (score 0):

Based on this question another POI user provided me an example .docx. Find below the POI code to generate a .docx containing [CustomXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.customxmlpart) elements, which can be selected via VBA.

The GUID can be used to retrieve the CustomXMLPart via the [SelectByID method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.customxmlparts.selectbyid)

The customXml XmlBeans used below need the [poi-ooxml-full](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.apache.poi%20AND%20a:poi-ooxml-full) artifact instead of the default poi-ooxml-lite artifact.

```
import static org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipTypes.CUSTOM_PROPERTIES;
import static org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipTypes.CUSTOM_XML;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLProperties;
import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLTypeLoader;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ContentTypes;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartName;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagingURIHelper;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.TargetMode;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.customProperties.CTProperty;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.customXml.CTDatastoreItem;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.customXml.DatastoreItemDocument;

public class TestCustomXML {

    private static final String CUSTOM_DOCPROP_TYPE = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.custom-properties+xml";
    private static final String CUSTOM_PROP_TYPE = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.customXmlProperties+xml";
    private static final String CUSTOM_PROP_REL = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/customXmlProps";


    private interface PartWriter {
        void write(Writer os) throws IOException;
    }

    @Test
    public void addXml() throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
        // Generate GUID
        final String guid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString().toUpperCase();
        try (XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
             FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("customxml.docx")) {

            PackagePart partItm =
                createPart(doc, "/customXml/item1.xml", ContentTypes.PLAIN_OLD_XML, doc.getPackagePart(), CUSTOM_XML, (osw) -> {
                osw.write("<myxml><foo>baa</foo></myxml>");
            });

            DatastoreItemDocument did = DatastoreItemDocument.Factory.newInstance();
            CTDatastoreItem di = did.addNewDatastoreItem();
            di.setItemID(guid);
            di.addNewSchemaRefs();

            createPart(doc, "/customXml/itemProps1.xml", CUSTOM_PROP_TYPE, partItm, CUSTOM_PROP_REL, (osw) -> {
                did.save(osw, POIXMLTypeLoader.DEFAULT_XML_OPTIONS);
            });

            org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.customProperties.PropertiesDocument custProp =
                org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.customProperties.PropertiesDocument.Factory.newInstance();
            CTProperty prop = custProp.addNewProperties().addNewProperty();
            prop.setFmtid(POIXMLProperties.CustomProperties.FORMAT_ID);
            prop.setName("mycustom_name_value");
            prop.setPid(2);
            prop.setLpwstr("1,2");

            createPart(doc, "/docProps/custom.xml", CUSTOM_DOCPROP_TYPE, null, CUSTOM_PROPERTIES, (osw) -> {
                custProp.save(osw, POIXMLTypeLoader.DEFAULT_XML_OPTIONS);
            });


            doc.write(fos);
        }
    }

    private static PackagePart createPart(XWPFDocument doc, String name, String contentType, PackagePart source, String relType, PartWriter writer)
    throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
        PackagePartName ppn = PackagingURIHelper.createPartName(name);
        OPCPackage opc = doc.getPackage();
        PackagePart part = opc.createPart(ppn, contentType);
        if (source == null) {
            opc.addRelationship(ppn, TargetMode.INTERNAL, relType);
        } else {
            source.addRelationship(ppn, TargetMode.INTERNAL, relType);
        }
        try (OutputStream os = part.getOutputStream();
             OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            writer.write(osw);
        }
        return part;
    }
}
```